# Continuing functions for chrome extensions-javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

so I am working on a really small chrome extension. There is a webpage and I want to click the buttons on this webpage. After I click all of them I want to click the next page button and keep doing the same thing.

I have no problem finding the buttons or the nextpagebutton. I am also able to do it using setInterval functions but I feel like it is kind of a hacky way to do this.

The below code is what I have so far

```
function clickButtons(){

    var followButtons = $('.buttonClass');
    var numberOfButtons = followButtons.length;

    for(var i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++){
        followButtons[i].click();
    }
    setTimeout(nextPage, 500);
}

function nextPage(){

    var nextPageBtn = $('.nextPageButtonClass');
    nextPageBtn.click();    

    setTimeout(clickButtons,500);
}
```

so my question is
1. My for loop to click all the buttons is not working. Is there a better way to click every button class?
2. I need to call the second function after the first one. And when the second one is finished, I need to call the first one again and they must follow each other constantly. I tried setting a timeout and calling the other one ın both functions. But it is not working. How can I do this?

This code basically doesn't do anything. And I have been scratching my head. Sorry I am a huge javascript noob

Comment: so what´s the question?

Comment: just edited my question. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: try debuggin numberOfButtons for starters, maybe there are none so that´s why nothing happens. Not sure how are you making the extension, but maybe you can´t directly access dom like that